# Two divs side by side, one centered and the other one float right

Tags: html, css, alignment

Embarrassingly, I'm having trouble making one div (of any length) centered and one div (of any length) floating on the right. So I have a container with menu buttons that are centered and a link to the users control panel on the right. It should look something like this

```
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                       |----Menu Items----|                |--ControlPanel--|
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I know, this question has probably been asked a few times but I've searched through and through and they all seem to rely on percentages or fixed widths.

I have a container

```
.container {
    height: 50px;   
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}
.menublock {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
.controllinks {
    float:right;    
}
```

The html is like this

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="menublock">
        <span class="menuitem">Streams</span>
        <span class="menuitem">Profile</span>
        <span class="menuitem">Friends</span>
    </div>
    <div class="controllinks">
        A link the users control panel
    </div>
</div>
```

By changing menublock and controllinks to `display:inline-block` (or inline) I can get them on the same line just fine. `.menublock`  does not seem to like being centered in this display and `margin: 0 auto;` doesn't work. I was messing around with `.menublock` `display:table` but that didn't want to stay on the same row.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe it was too easy so you didn't even try it, but this fixed the thing in my test file: Just swap the order of `<div class="controllinks">` and `<div class="menublock">`:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="controllinks">
        A link the users control panel
    </div>
    <div class="menublock">
        <span class="menuitem">Streams</span>
        <span class="menuitem">Profile</span>
        <span class="menuitem">Friends</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked great. In all honesty I never would have tried that. Thanks!

Comment: When using float always keep in mind that only the elements that come after the floated element float around it. The ones before usually don't.

Answer (score 3):

An easy solution is to use absolute positioning.

```
.container {
    height: 50px;   
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    /*this makes the child divs relative to the parent*/
    position:relative;
}
.menublock {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
.controllinks {
    /*this puts the controllinks on the right. 
    Be warned, that if the page is too small, controllinks can no overlap on menublock. 
    This can be fixed with media queries.*/
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;  
}
```

Comment: This definitely worked, I wanted to avoid using absolutes in this case. See my other comment for another solution I found

Comment: @DeepakBhalla Yeah, that's understandable. His solution appears to be easier/better in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Both Merlin's and James' solutions worked well. They all achieved the same result.

Another solution I just found was adding `text-align: center;` to the `.container` class. It turns out inline elements respond to text-align (although it seems strange to think of divs in this way).