# Two divs side-by-side—one in the centre, the other on the right

Tags: html, css

I am building a website on Weebly (I feel like this will be frowned upon, but I don't have much time to do it). I want the organisation's logo in the centre, with social buttons at the top right, with a margin of 5px on the top and bottom. In the html, I have this:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="social">{social}</div>
    <div id="sitename">{logo}</div>
</div>
```

Here's how the header and sitename ids are defined

```
#header {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}

#sitename a,
#sitename a:link,
#sitename a:visited {
    color: #484848;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 36px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: url('teal_icons.png') -9999px -9999px no-repeat;
    margin: auto;
}

#social {
    float: right;
}
```

I tried following the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26597988/two-divs-side-by-side-one-centered-and-the-other-one-float-right), but it didn't help.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this

```
#social {
    float: left;
    width: 200px; /*Your width here*/
}

#sitename {
    margin-left: 200px; /*Your width here*/
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#header {
    overflow: hidden; /*If not do this margin top will not work*/
}
```

Comment: float left says that element should be pushed left side and other wrap around. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Comment: @agu-f catched a good point, clear is needed, because other elements after header can wrap social too if sitename hasn't enough width

Answer (score 2):

This could help.

CSS:

```
#header {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}
#sitename {
    color: #484848;
    font-family:'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 36px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: auto;
    text-align:center;
}
#social {
    float: right;
    text-align-right;
}
.clear { clear:both }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="social">[FB] [TW] [IN] [..]</div>
    <div id="sitename">LOGO OF <br/> YOUR COMPANY</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**CSS**

```
#header {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}

#sitename a,
#sitename a:link,
#sitename a:visited {
    color: #484848;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 36px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: url('teal_icons.png') -9999px -9999px no-repeat;
    margin: auto;
}

#sitename:before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  clear:both;
}

#social {
    float:right;
    margin:5px 0;
}
```

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/roughtron/pen/XJbmrG)